# graphics behind a PNG shows through

Tags: image

After importing a few PNG files to Blender files successfully, I ran into a problem recently.  The PNG file I imported appeared "see through".  Please see attachments.  As you can see in the rendering the back wall and fake shadows behind the PNG file of the bench all appear in front of the bench.  I Also attached the texture settings for the bench PNG.  I don't have this problem in my other Blender files.  Does anyone know what might have caused this undesirable see through effect?  Thank you!

[image: texture settings for the PNG file]

[image: The back wall can show through the PNG file]

Comment: This could be a [sorting problem](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/eevee/materials/settings.html#sorting-problem). Try to set the *Blend Mode* to *Alpha Hashed*.

Comment: Did you double check the actual transparency of the source PNG in photoshop or another image editing program?

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Yes.  I have checked to make sure the PNG file had a transparent background in Photoshop before saving it as PNG.  After deleting a few elements from the file, such as environmental texture, some meshes in the same file, the problem appear to have been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not wish for the wood to be transparent, I suggest removing the Transparent BSDF, and perhaps changing the blend mode to Opaque;

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion!  Blender automatically set PNG images to transparent BSDF when importing the image.  If setting it to principle BSDF, the rest of the PNG photo will show, which defeats the purpose of seamlessly mixing this PNG in the 3D setting.  I was told in a tutorial to set  "Alpha Blend" for blend mode, so the rest of the PNG image would be transparent.  If not it will be black.

Comment: I did experiment with turning the shader to principle BSDF, and setting blend mode to opaque.  The PNG image's background showed up, not my intended goal.  My other PNG files are not see through like this.  I wonder if I accidently clicked on some setting, or this is a bug.  If anyone has encountered this and fixed the problem, please keep me posted.  Thanks.

Comment: I could confirm these things with a copy of your .blend file. You can upload it here; https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Thank you.  It was a huge file.  I deleted many textured elements to bring down the file size.  I did a render right before I saved the file, and the "see-through" problem was mysterious resolved somehow.  Nonetheless, if there's a better way to stage a PNG in Blender than using transparent BSDF and Alpha Blend, I am open to new ideas.  Does this URL for the uploaded file help?  https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/m7rEyPS2   Thanks!

Comment: Why... would you *ever* use transparent? What is the goal? What do you mean by "stage"?

Comment: I want to show the bench furniture from a 2D photo in a room setting, so I imported the photo into this 3D room setting in Blender.  The end result is a room setting render of the furniture.  To make the 2d furniture photo to not show as a cut and paste job in the 3d setting, I had to drop its boarder etc., so the render looks realistic.  That's why I had to import the 2d photo as a PNG with a transparent background.